# How to loop values in table valued function in C# though Entity framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

First list is where we are getting all emails id's and the second list is where we  have to loop in table valued function in c#.

```
var user_emailIDs = Ent.PS_ResourceDetails
                   .Where(x => resourceNames.Contains(x.ResourceName))
                   .Select(x => x.ResourceEmailAddress)
                   .ToList();// first list getting email id's

var record2 = Ent.tf_Resource_Estimated_by_manager(user_emailIDs, 1, 2017)
                   .ToList();// second list loop all emailids to get records
```

Please let me know how can i loop.Thanks in advance.

Comment: so you want to loop trough `record2` right?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if i understood your question, but i think i did.

```
var record2 = Ent.tf_Resource_Estimated_by_manager(x=> user_emailIDs.Contains(x.EmailId))
               .ToList();
```

Contains can be used with list too.
I think its translated as SELECT IN () in SQL.